# How did trial get its definition?

Tags: meaning, etymology

So, I think we all know that one definition of **trial** is...
(from [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trial)
)

> The formal examination before a competent tribunal of the matter in issue in a civil or criminal cause in order to determine such issue

My question is how did **trial** get the definition

> a tryout or experiment to test quality, value, or usefulness — compare

?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> #### Trial (n.)
>
> - mid-15c., "act or process of testing, a putting to proof by examination, experiment, etc.," from Anglo-French *trial*, noun formed from *triet* "to try" (see [try](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=try&allowed_in_frame=0) (v.)). Sense of "examining and deciding of the issues between parties in a court of law" is first recorded 1570s; extended to any ordeal by 1590s. As an adjectival phrase, *trial-and-error* is recorded from 1806. *Trial balloon* (1826) translates French *ballon d'essai*, a small balloon sent up immediately before a manned ascent to determine the direction and tendency of winds in the upper air, though the earliest use in English is figurative.

([EtymOnline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=trial&allowed_in_frame=0))

> #### Try (v.)
>
> - c. 1300, "examine judiciously, discover by evaluation, test;" mid-14c., "sit in judgment of," also "attempt to do," from Anglo-French *trier* (13c.), from Old French *trier* "to pick out, cull" (12c.), from Gallo-Roman *triare*, of unknown origin. The ground sense is "separate out (the good) by examination." Sense of "subject to some strain" (of patience, endurance, etc.) is recorded from 1530s. To *try on* "test the fit of a garment" is from 1690s; to *try (something) on for size* in the figurative sense is recorded by 1946. *Try and* instead of *try to* is recorded from 1680s.

([EtymOnline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=try&allowed_in_frame=0))

Comment: How does this post answer the question?

Comment: How is this post not general reference?

Comment: @Emereal But as Martha has said: '‘If we accept the axiom that [such] questions are bad for the site, then the proper response to a general reference question is: 1.Don't answer! 2… [Vote] to close. The point is not to encourage trivial questions. If you post an answer or vote up an existing answer, you're implicitly encouraging more questions like it." (I didn't close-vote your question as I think the Etymon material does not provide a full answer. If you consider it does, one wonders why you hadn't consulted Etymon, recommended on ELU as a general reference, yourself.)

Comment: @Hank I agree, but this is not general reference. I had no idea what EtymOnline was until today.

Comment: @Hank Surely site policy carries more weight than X's personal opinion here. See [Please help define the limits of general reference](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4013/please-help-define-the-limits-of-general-reference) on meta.

Comment: @Hank It's my opinion Etymon _is_ general reference. It has been considered as such here for years. This is why we have site policies rather than a free-for-all.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I do agree it was on me for not reading that section. But I think you could've ended the argument at the very beginning by stating that fact. I don't mean it as an attack or a jab at you, just stating that. I don't mean for you to take offense or anything, it is on me for not reading that section fully.